# find a smallest nuclear $C^*$ algebra containing set S

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $S$ is a set ,can we find a smallest nuclear $C^*$ algebra containing $S$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are C$^*$-algebras that are not contained in any nuclear C$^*$-algebra. Any non-exact algebra would give the counterexample, as exactness passes to subalgebras.

Comment: If A is a nuclear C* algebra,does there exist a general method to construct a smallest nuclear C^* algebra B which contains A?

Comment: That would be $A$.